# Copying a file from an IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, wpf, security, isolatedstorage

I was just wondering if there is a way to prevent people from copying a file which is stored by using System.IO.IsolatedStorage? To me, I can't think of anyway. Any person can go and grab those files manually. Is there other ways that I am missing?

Comment: Can you more clearly characterize what *threat* you are worried about, what *vulnerability* you think that isolated storage might have, and what *resource* needs to be protected? I find it easier to answer security questions when the threat, vulnerability and resource are clearly defined. (Real life example, for clarity: threat = burglars.  vulnerability = unlocked window.  resource to be protected from threat = your TV set.)

Comment: well, actually I was more worried if somebody would go and grab those files. I don't want anybody except the one who created them would have access to them.

Comment: OK, so the resource is the files. The vulnerability is that the files can be grabbed. Who is the threat? Is "somebody" you (the user), another program running on your behalf, your machine administrator, your network administrator, another user on your machine, a backup operator, an evil hacker ten thousand miles away?  The techniques you'd use to protect your files from being grabbed by an untrustworthy backup operator are VERY different than the techniques used to protect your files from an evil hacker.

Comment: I would say anybody who can login to that machine, and grab the file. Well, I checked and if you login with a different username, you don't have access to those folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolated storage is linked to the logged in user and stored under their profile only. So with out-of-the-box NTFS ACL's in place, no other user can access these files.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx):

*Data is stored in compartments that are isolated by the current user and by the assembly in which the code exists. Additionally, data can be isolated by domain. Roaming profiles can be used in conjunction with isolated storage so isolated stores will travel with the user's profile.*

So, not just *any* person can copy them, only the person under which' context they were created can.

Is that not secure enough?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. So what you are referring is that unless a user is logged in with the same account you were logged in while creating those files, you cannot find those folders and manually copy/paste the file into another folder, right? if it's the case, which is my expected case, I would say it's very secure.

Comment: That is correct. Isolated storage files are stored in the user's "Application Data" folder and therefore cannot be accessed by different users.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated storage is designed to keep your program data fenced in rather than keeping other applications out, Data is ring fenced from other .net programs running under reduced permission sets. Data is stored in local or roaming user compartments and cannot be accessed via ordinary file streams only via IsolatedStorageFileStream.

In short though if another program really wanted access it could, but you would have to deliberately set out to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For example, your laptop is stolen and there are files in the Isolated Storage.

If the thief run the drive like slave or starts an ubuntu live for example could access to these files.